# Deployment multiply releases at once

Tags: azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have got about 30+ services. Each service has it's own repository, build and release on different environments.
Is it possible to deploy all releases for the latest build artifacts on the specified environment by single command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn’t the built-in command can do it, but you can build a app (e.g. console application, PowerShell) to create release through Rest API: [Create a release](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/rm/releases#create-a-release)

Answer (score 0):

You can create an overarching Release pipeline that use all the build artifacts. The downsides of this option are:

- duplication of "code" between the single-component pipeline and the overarching one, mitigate using Task Groups
- you do not have a simple display of what is deployed in an environment because you have to look in two places (single-component and overarching)